# SQL Selecting non-null rows conditionally

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like the below on teradata.

Each customer can have a max of 2 rows in the table - one with the address populated and one with address as null. So some customers can have only one row with an address. Some can have only one row with no address. Some can have 2 rows, one with address and one without address.

I want an output table with one row per customer - if there is an address, then I want that row, if not I want the null row. I've tried playing with case statements and where statements but I can't seem to get them to work. Seems like I need something like a max function for text.

**Table 1**:

```
cust_id     address
1           abc
1   
2   
3           xyz
```

**Output**:

```
cust_id      address
1            abc
2   
3            xyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` clause together with `max` aggregate function:

```
select cust_id, max(address)
from tbl
group by cust_id
```

Comment: thanks, I just updated my post saying I think I needed a max function for text. I didn't realize I could use max on text. will try and confirm.

Comment: If these are true nulls you could even use `min()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `group by` method is the simplest method to express.  It is possible that with the right indexes, `union all` would have better performance:

```
select *
from tbl
where address is not null
union all
select *
from tbl t2
where address is null and
      not exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t.cust_id = t2.cust_id and t2.address is not null);
```

Note:  This has the advantage/disadvantage of keeping all non-NULL values for a given `cust_id`.